# Settlers of Catan : "Can we build after rolling a 7"

Tags: catan

In Settlers of Catan (base game or the 5-6 player expansion). **Can we build after  rolling a seven.?**  As per the FAQ here: http://www.catan.com/faqs/93?page=3

I know I can't trade with others and can play any one development card, but what about Maritime trade?.

**I was confused because on the same above mentioned FAQ page it said : You can continue with your normal turn after rolling a 7.** If you can't trade with other what is this "Normal" here. Please help on this

Comment: All these answers and comments have parts, but no one has explained the confusion in the question between the time you can't trade or build, and the time you continue with your normal turn where you can

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can do anything after roling a 7.

You won't get any new resources. If you have too much, you must return some. And you can move the robber.

Comment: Just to be sure of what anything/all I can do. Catan FAQ says I can't trade with others after rolling a 7. So you mean after rolling a 7 I can build, Maritime trade and open Development card. right?

Comment: @Joker There's no contradiction there. The FAQ say you can't trade with others after rolling a 7 *before moving the robber*.  After you move the robber and steal a resource, you carry on with your turn as normal, including all the things you mention *and trading*.

Comment: @Joker Moving the robber as a result of a 7 happens during the Resource Production phase. Trading happens during the Trade phase. You can still trade after you have rolled a 7, the FAQ entry is just clarifying that you cannot trade after rolling a 7, but before moving the robber, since the trade would happen out-of-phase in this case.

Comment: After playing so many games of Settlers of Catan and knowing this know makes me feel so Stupid. Clarifying this to my friends whom I misinformed would be a different level of fun now. Thanks @Jefromi

Answer (score 15):

To quote the [FAQ](http://www.catan.com/faq/4645-seven-and-robber-after-rolling-7-can-i-still-trade-another-player-or-blackmail-him-moving):

> **Q:** After rolling a “7,” can I still trade with another player or blackmail him before moving the robber?
>
> **A:** Trading: No. (...)

This is to prevent players from using a trade to save themselves from the robber. After moving the robber, you can do whatever you want: build, trade, play development cards... just like any other turn.

Comment: The keyword is *blackmail him before moving the robber?*. You can't trade BEFORE you move the robber as @freekvd points out to prevent people from getting hit but you can trade AFTER moving the robber.